# Invalid column name 'UserId' and 'IdentityUser_Id' when trying to log-in/register

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, ef-model-builder

I have been trying to build my own online shop in MVC based on the OpenOrderFramework located here - https://github.com/lbacaj/OpenOrderFramework

I've managed to get everything working perfectly apart from when it comes to trying to log in, register, or complete checkout - basically anything to do with Identity.

The error I keep getting is either:

```
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
```

or

```
Invalid column name 'IdentityUser_UserId'.
```

As part of the process, I have created my own custom AspNet Identity tables (AspNetRoles, AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUsers)

When I say custom, they all follow the standardised default format apart from the AspNetUsers table which has some additional new fields in there. They are nevertheless fed into the project like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
 base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("TSSC_AspNetUsers", "dbo");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("TSSC_AspNetUsers", "dbo");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("TSSC_AspNetUserRoles", "dbo");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("TSSC_AspNetRoles", "dbo");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("TSSC_AspNetUserLogins", "dbo");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("TSSC_AspNetUserClaims", "dbo");

 }
```

Depending on what I try, the invalid column name error can appear up to three times for the same field which I find odd.

I took a look at the SQL query string being generated inside the UserManager and this is what it returned:

```
+            
((Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TSSC.Models.ApplicationUser,string>)(UserManager)).Users    {SELECT 
'0X0X' AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[IdentityUser_Id] AS [IdentityUser_Id], 
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
[Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
[Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
[Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
[Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
[Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
[Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
[Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
[Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
FROM [dbo].[TSSC_AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'ApplicationUser'}    
System.Linq.IQueryable<TSSC.Models.ApplicationUser> 
{System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TSSC.Models.ApplicationUser>}
```

As you can see, it is looking for a column called 'IdentityUser_UserId' which doesn't exist. The field is actually 'Id'.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. This is driving me nuts.